# How to trigger `error` action *outside* of a transition

Tags: ember.js, error-handling

I'm looking to implement some consistent error handling in my app through the `error` action. The problem I've run into is that it is only triggered when an exception is raised *while in a transition*, and not, for example, in a plain `saveModelInResponseToUserClick` action on a route.

I can sort of get something to work with the following, but it's a hack:

```
Ember.onerror = function(error) {
  MyApp.__container__.lookup('router:main').send('handleError')
}
```

With that, I could have different error-handling logic in differently-nested routes.

EDIT: Another issue with using the method above is when an error occurs before the app has fully transitioned into its first route - another exception is raised in that case and everything blows up.

Is there a different approach I can take with this?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the error action will only trigger while in transition.

For errors that may arise from an action, you could try using the following:

```
Ember.RSVP.on('error', function(error) {

// handle error

}
```

This will catch ANY error that occurs as a result of a promise in your app. You can access the "error" object inside the function, which will give you some detail as to what exactly went wrong, particularly the "responseText" attribute. The code itself goes in your app.js file.

Ember docs on this: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_errors-within-an-code-rsvp-promise-code